# EF code first create database on start up with sqlclient provider

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a database on startup with this code:

```
class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

    public DataContext() : base("Database")
    {
        Database.Initialize(true);

    }

}

/////////
try
{
var db = new DataContext();

db.Students.Add(new Student());

db.SaveChanges();
}

catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

//app.config

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Database"
            connectionString="Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;
            AttachDbFileName=C:\Users\Aaron\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\EF Test\EF Test\bin\Debug\MyData.mdf"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

I think my connection string is bad. I've tried about a dozen with no luck. I get an exception on my Initialize call. "An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file failed". thanks for the help.

EDIT 
Changed this:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Database"
        connectionString="Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;
        database=C:\Users\Aaron\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\EF Test\EF Test\bin\Debug\MyData.mdf"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>\
```

and now i get "Additional information: Cannot open database "C:\Users\Aaron\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\EF Test\EF Test\bin\Debug\MyData.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed."

Comment: Yes, the connection string is bad. It tells the server to attach an existing database file instead of just specyfing the database name.

Comment: So if I change AttachDbFileName to database I get an error saying I cant login. Isn't integrated security supposed to fix that?

Comment: This possibly is because you haven't set up the initializer `Database.SetInitializer<DataContext>( new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DataContext>() )` prior to connecting to it.

Comment: Hmm I tried that but no luck. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. So I created a local database in visual studios Server Explorer->Connect to database. Once I created the database I copied the connection string that looks like this:

```
<add name="dbtest" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Aaron\Desktop\mydb.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

and bam worked like a charm. Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Database"
             connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb);Database=MyData.mdf;Trusted_Connection=True" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I noticed type in data source. Did you fix the type? If not try again, otherwise could you give me the inner most message of the exception

Comment: Yes I did fix the typo. Also I have to set the provider to providerName="System.Data.SqlClient". The inner exception is "The parameter is incorrect". doesn't say which one.

Comment: changing the string to   <add name="Database1"
      connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Database=MyData.mdf;Trusted_Connection=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> gives me the same login error as in my edit.

Comment: Check if you have write permission on that folder. And make sure that .mdf file does not already exist and is locked out

Comment: I tried a few different paths no luck though. Same login error.

Comment: Does your user have full read/write acess to that folder? It is possible that you are running Visual Studio under admin, which has access to the output folder, but once you run the actuall app as you, You do not have access. Try setting the Output folder (and its subdirs) to Full Access to Users group

Comment: I changed the path to the desktop. should that be sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

See [here.](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-in-code-first.aspx)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SchoolDBConnectionString" 
    connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=SchoolDB-ByConnectionString;Integrated Security=true" 
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

So Code First will create a new SchoolDB-ByConnectionString database.

Comment: This one gives me: Cannot open database "SchoolDB-ByConnectionString" requested by the login. The login failed. how do I specify the path?

Comment: Did you use windows authentication?  Integrated Security=SSPI should work for windows authentication. Put your new connection string please.

Comment: Please also [Enable a Server Network Protocol](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191294.aspx).

Comment: Tried the integrated security but no change. If I had to install the app on another machine would I have to run that script there too?

Comment: Try to create a new database by Sql server managemant studio, let's us know any problem. Perhaps it is the permission issue. Also try to look up the databases to see if the database was created by the above method.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below code

```
<add name="ConStr" 
         connectionString="Data Source=LAPTOP-H3027NJJ\SQLEXPRESS2019;Database=SchoolDB;User Id=Sa;Password=admin@123;Integrated Security=True;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: Hi, what's the gist of your solution / connection string? It's simpler to understand with a bit of comment